# How to Right aligned xAxis Label in HighChart when we are working with two column series without stacking: 'normal',

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

xAxis Label alignment should start from red mark plot..

keeping image for the reference

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8T73.png)

I was trying with label formatter

```
 xAxis: {
            categories: [],
            min:0,
            labels: {
                useHTML: true,
                align: 'center',
                allowOverlap: false,
                style: {
                    color: '#000000'
                },
                formatter: function () {
                   return <html><body><div style="position:absolute;right:14px;font-size:small;"><p>${this.value}</p></div></body></html>`;
                 }
            }
        },
```

Comment: I reproduced your example in the working demo and it seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/07uzq5jw/

Comment: @magdalena Please refer this image regarding expected alignment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8T73.png

Also, if any datapoint is missing in a set then where it will get aligned as it occupies the area in the chart even there is no value to plot the bar. Please have a look jsfiddle.net/rajputshaily/u45mbqk8/3

Comment: The labels behaviour is related to the ticks. I think you can use a different approach here like changing pointPlacement - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7wk2frbL/

Comment: @magdalena Thanks for the response..
it is working fine if i have more than one data ..but it is breaking in case of single data . It is breaking at the time of plotting of single data is quit far from y axis ideally it should not.

for reference: - https://jsfiddle.net/rajputshaily/chb2eqdo/4/

i tried another scenario by keeping condition for single data if it contain single data its point placement should be 0. again, i am facing issue in x axis label alignment.

please suggest accordingly.

Comment: You can adjust the space between column and axis, via `xAxis.min`: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d2joe9r0/